# Closing thin gaps created by the boundary of a polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, slivers, gap

I am working in QGIS 3 and I have a shape file containing many polygons. Several of the polygons have very thin gaps created by the bounding line of the polygon and they do not penetrate the entire width of the polygons - see the attached picture: [image: gaps] I have tried several methods to remove these with no success. I have tried the v.clean, remove holes, simplify and generalize functions and none of these were successful

Is there a technique that can be used to remove these gaps?

Comment: Try the [`v.clean`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.clean.html)

Comment: Try snap to grid

Comment: What parameters did you use in v.clean?  Is the tolerance you used in v.clean larger than the size of the gap?  There is also a snap geometries to layer tool where the parameters are important including snap tolerance and whether vertices can be added.

Comment: I tried both setting a threshold and using the default options for v.clean - neither worked for removing these thin gaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a buffer with a size that it covers the hole. Than apply another buffer with the same, but negative value.

Comment: I don’t really recommend doing this

Comment: Why not? Because geometry might change?

Comment: Ja genau. Check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291093/dissolving-neighbour-bordering-polygon-features-in-qgis

Comment: I would say it heavily depends on the data and the needs - what you want to achieva and what requirements there are for precision.

Comment: So far this approach works. For my purpose the geometries do not need to be highly accurate. A small buffer is acceptable.

Comment: If it works and you don't need high precision, then I would stick with the method - quick and dirty, so to say...